# How to set the text and detail text of cell in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I am getting this type of data inside cell. How to set the text and detail text of cell so that both text may appear in readable format.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0 ];

    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UILabel *idLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:201];
    if(!idLabel)
    {
        idLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        idLabel.tag = 201;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:idLabel];

    }
    idLabel.text = [arrayFiltered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;



    return cell;
}
```

The code which i have written is above.
Please help me.

Comment: you can use custom table view cell as per your design requirements.

Comment: why are you adding idLabel?

Comment: user6438311 check my answer

Answer (score 2):

We have 3 or more options to achieve this.I explain you step by step process
I create the tableView and hook up.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"  // For CustomCell using,we have to import.
@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSMutableArray *idArray;
  NSMutableArray *descArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
```

In viewDidLoad method I added the objects to id desc array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"INOX",@"Sathyam",@"PVR",@"IMAX",nil];
  descArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"INOX currently operates 107 multiplexes and 420 screens in 57 cities across India",@"SPI Cinemas is an Indian multiplex chain and film production company owned by the SPI Group, headquartered in Chennai.",@"The IMAX cinema process increases the image resolution by using larger film frame;",@"PVR Cinemas is the largest and the most premium film entertainment company in India.",nil];
}
```

Below tableView datasource methods

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return idArray.count;
}
```

Now I have 3 options for achieving your requirement.But all these are implemented in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

**FIRST OPTION:UITableViewCellStyleDefault**-If you use this, you can implement the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath like below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *strCell = @"cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
  if(cell==nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
  }

  UILabel *idLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  idLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 13, 168, 24);
  idLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
  idLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
  idLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
  idLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:idLabel];

  UILabel *descLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  descLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 47, 348, 34);
  descLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
  descLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
  descLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
  descLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  descLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  descLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:descLabel];

  return cell;
}
```

**SECOND OPTION:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle** - If you use this, you can implement the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath like below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *strCell = @"cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
  if(cell==nil)
  {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:strCell];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  cell.textLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
  cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
  cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
  cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  cell.detailTextLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
  cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
  cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
  cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

  return cell;
}
```

**THIRD OPTION : CUSTOM CELL** - If you use Custom Cell you have to import the CustomCell.h first.After that you have to do the following things in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
   if(cell == nil){
     cell = nib[0];
   }
   cell.idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   cell.idLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
   cell.idLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
   cell.idLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
   cell.idLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
   cell.idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

   cell.descLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   cell.descLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
   cell.descLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
   cell.descLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
   cell.descLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
   cell.descLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

   return cell;
 }
```

I attached the screen shot of custom cell.It shows you what I have done there.

**SNAPCHAT 1:idLabel**

[image]

**SNAPCHAT 2:descLabel**

[image]

You can use heightForRowAtIndexPath method for setting row height.It is UITableViewDelegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 90;
}
```

> NOTE:Generally  I set the tag for label is idLabel.tag = indexPath.row.According
>   to your requirement set the tag here.

I created and worked out the sample application for you.All I have done successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use cell textLable and detailTextLable to show your data like below code-

```
cell.textLabel.text=@"your text";


cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"your text";
```

Answer (score 0):

idLabel overrides the position of the textlabel . 
If 
 you want to put the id before the text , You can combine both the string and put into the textlabel. 
else
    use dont use textlabel and detail textlabel, create all the three labels of your own and align properly using Frame values.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Height of the Cell and calculate it according to the Cell Text and number of lines of Label. And move your Font, Background Color, Line Break settings of label inside cell == nil.

**Edit:** to adjust three Labels you would need custom Cell or if you can concatenate it with Text Label. It all depends on your requirement.

Comment: how to adjust the height of cell according to the text? can you help me

Comment: You need Three labels in three different positions?